# Detecting when a child is added dynamically

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have using `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView`to add templates to a `parent` component. In the templates I have `child` elements handled by my custom `child` directive.
I'm trying to detect when the children is created using `@Query(Child)` and `QueryList` but when the child is added the `QueryList` subscribe callback isn't called.

How to detect when a child element is added (dynamically) to the parent?

Example [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JH7acOXvOOnml53WoIk6?p=preview)

In the example you can see that parent render a `div` for each child component, if you press `add` button a child is added, you can see in developers tools that `child` elements are added and a console message is outputed but the QueryList isn't updated ...

Any ideas?

***Update RC6:***

`@Query()` has been removed on RC6, I have updated the plunker to use `@ContentChildren` and `@ViewChildren`, and the result is the same, neither detect the new elements added by `ViewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView`.

In addition, I have added in the plunker a functionallity to get elements by `getElementsByTagName("child")` and this works but I think this way isn't the best.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using OnChanges? It is a hook that will update whenever an input has changed, it will provide a json list of the declarations and values that u can compare and handle.

```
import {OnChanges} from '@angular/core'

class implements OnChanges


ngOnChanges(){
//handle changes
}
```

Comment: Mistake #4:  Using ngOnChanges to detect query list changes http://angularjs.blogspot.com.es/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html

Comment: Well, not necessarily a mistake if you do it on purpose haha but I am aware that it is not the best practice to default to.